# Place a layer on top of the street view - Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering if there is a way I can place an image on top of a building in google maps street view and as I pan that view, this image would follow the exact same building x,y and z.

I know I can redraw the webgl sphere on top of the street view image, but I am not sure how precise it will be.

Any idea about how to do it using the GM API?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.paintyourstreet.com/ (there were also a couple of other sites that don't seem to work anymore)

Comment: From this blog: http://www.mapsmaniac.com/2011/05/add-graffiti-to-google-maps-street-view.html (there are some other options as well)